# Group query result rows by column value while iterating

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have an array from this:

```
$biaya = odbc_exec($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM example");
$no = 0;
while (odbc_fetch_row($biaya)) {
    $no++;
    $sub_title = odbc_result($biaya, "subtitle");
    $title = odbc_result($biaya, "title");
}
```

If I display the looping it will be like this:

[image]

I want to split the array based on the subtitle. i want to get array like this :

[image]

[image]

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Instead of cretainf two seperate array variable this is more good:- `$array=array(0=>array(
array(no="1",subtitle="Perbekalan", title="lombok ijo"),
array(no="2",subtitle="Perbekalan", title="bawang abang")),1=>array(
array(no="3",subtitle="Inventaris", title="Wajan"))
);`. Don't you think so? Also how you are creating `$array`? that code part is missing. So add that

Comment: array_slice would be useful\

Comment: try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh i will echoing this looping (while) in table. so $array is just a metaphor

Comment: @satewedos  so you don't want two different variables, just want to reform array based on subtitles?

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh no. i want to echoing in two different tables

Comment: @satewedos do you use mysql?

Comment: @splash58 im using SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is more preferable to use some PHP adapter like `Eloquent` or `Doctrine` instead of running raw queries.
2. Use `order by`.

   select * from example order by subtitle
3. In the `while` loop, please use following trick.

```

```
$temp = null;

$result = [];
while(odbc_fetch_row($biaya)) {
   $no++;
   $sub_title=odbc_result($biaya,"subtitle");
   $title=odbc_result($biaya,"title");
   if($temp != $sub_title) {
      $result[$sub_title] = ["no" => $no, "subtitle" => $sub_title, "title" => $title];
      $temp = $sub_title;


   }
   else {
      $result[$sub_title][] = ["no" => $no, "subtitle" => $sub_title, "title" => $title];
   }
}
```

```

Comment: there will be many subtitles later on. sorry i just give example 2 subtitle

Comment: @satewedos this will work even if you have more than 2 subtitles.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below:-

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row){
    $result[$row['subtitle']][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: this will not create two different variables.As OP asked

Comment: It is arguably more professional to keep related data confined to a single array/variable versus increasing the number of variables in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution.. you can see the result [here(update)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f9f23e476415b29fc0da9d5dd29195619b115d9)

i have update with `Inventaris` categories

```
   <?php
$array=array(
array("no"=>"1","subtitle"=>"Perbekalan", "title"=>"lombok ijo"),
array("no"=>"11","subtitle"=>"Perbekalan", "title"=>"lombok asdf"),
array("no"=>"2","subtitle"=>"Perbekalan", "title"=>"bawang abang"),
array("no"=>"3","subtitle"=>"Inventaris", "title"=>"Wajan")
);
echo "<pre>";
//print_r($array);
$Perbekalan=array();
$Inventaris=array();
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if($value['subtitle']=="Perbekalan")
    {
        $Perbekalan[$i]['no']=$value['no'];
        $Perbekalan[$i]['subtitle']=$value['subtitle'];
        $Perbekalan[$i]['title']=$value['title'];
    }
    if($value['subtitle']=="Inventaris")
    {
        $Inventaris[$i]['no']=$value['no'];
        $Inventaris[$i]['subtitle']=$value['subtitle'];
        $Inventaris[$i]['title']=$value['title'];
    }
    $i++;

}
echo "per";
print_r($Perbekalan);
echo "ins";
print_r($Inventaris);
?>
```

Comment: My array source is (while) instead of $ array. sorry if i write an ambiguous question

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$items=
array(
    array('no'=>"1", 'subtitle'=>"Perbekalan", 'title'=>"lombok ijo"),
    array('no'=>"3",'subtitle'=>"Inventaris", 'title'=>"Wajan"),
    array('no'=>"2",'subtitle'=>"Perbekalan", 'title'=>"bawang abang")
);

foreach($items as $item)
    $output[$item['subtitle']][] = $item;

extract($output);

var_export($Perbekalan);
echo "\n";
var_export($Inventaris);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'no' => '1',
      'subtitle' => 'Perbekalan',
      'title' => 'lombok ijo',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'no' => '2',
      'subtitle' => 'Perbekalan',
      'title' => 'bawang abang',
    ),
  )
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'no' => '3',
      'subtitle' => 'Inventaris',
      'title' => 'Wajan',
    ),
  )
```